# How to redirect from my project url to some root context

Tags: jsp

How to redirect from my project url to some root context. Like need to redirect from http://www.mysite/myapp/index.html to http://www.mysite.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using .htaccess where you can define 'translation' of web address into 'physical' address. Here's **[some reading](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)**

Provided you use Apache WS naturally ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can always redirect to root context using the URL root identifier `/` which  will point to domain/subdomains home page.

**Example :**

`http://site.subdomain.com/directories/myPage.html` can contain an anchor tag `<a href='/'>home</a>` which will directly take you to `http://site.subdomain.com`

same will work for redirects.